# Собственный поток ввода C

Tags: c, многопоточность, input, io

Есть прога. Требуется, чтобы основной цикл исполнялся независимо от ввода, но при этом надо чтобы присутствовал ввод getch(). Как организовать это в потоке? В интернете ничего подобного не нашёл.

Comment: `getch` это надо полагать, винда?

Comment: @Егор - "Как организовать это в потоке?"

- Вопрос не понятен. В одном потоке - никак. Надо из главной программы запустить **два** потока - в одном фоновая обработка, во втором - работа с консолью.  В чём проблема ?